# Need MS Access Form Field to automatically Calculate and Allocate Costs based on given Parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Below is my mock database that I am using. I have four different tables: *Tbl_MainDatabase, Tbl_InsuranceCoverage, Tbl_MatterDetail*, and *Tbl_PaymentProcessing*.

[image: Database]

**What I want** -

I want my form to determine the remaining *Retention Limit* (i.e., *Retention Limit* for the applicable policy - sum of invoices for the same *Claim Number* )

According to the mock database, the required answer should be [ $2500 - (300+700+355)]  as highlighted for your convenience

**What I tried**

I used the help of Graphical representation through the following query:

```
SELECT [Claim Number], Sum([Net Invoice Amount]) 
FROM [PaymentProcessing] 
GROUP BY [Claim Number]
```

This method works to show me how much I spent per claim number so far in the form of a graph. However I want to display the remaining amount.

Any Help is appreciated :)

I am one month old at using Access. But I am trying my best to learn

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For All the New users The above code by @Doug Coats works perfectly. 
**Make Sure** All the Foreign Key and Primary Keys is linked in the Relationship Property. ( One of the way To do this in the Query is - Right click on the Query and select Design View --> Right click  again on the grey space and Select Show all Tables Now Drag your Primary Key of the table and drop at the foreign Key on the other table --> This will create a relationship between both for the Query Purpose.

This will also Prevent Data from Duplication in the query then use a similar code as described by Doug Coats in the above comment in the **SQL View**

```
SELECT [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit]-Sum([Net Invoice Amount]) AS Remaining, [Matter Detail].[Claim Number], [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit], [Matter Detail].Policy
FROM (([Main Database] INNER JOIN [Matter Detail] ON [Main Database].[Database ID] = [Matter Detail].[Short Name]) INNER JOIN [Payment Processing] ON ([Matter Detail].[Matter Detail ID] = [Payment Processing].[Matter Detail ID]) AND ([Main Database].[Database ID] = [Payment Processing].[Short Name])) INNER JOIN [Insurance Coverage] ON [Matter Detail].Policy = [Insurance Coverage].[Insurance ID]
GROUP BY [Matter Detail].[Claim Number], [Insurance Coverage].[Retention Unit], [Matter Detail].Policy;
```

You can then display this query in the form -  I am still evaluating best way to display this query probably in a Combo Box (Not sure if any other controls has a row source)

Thank you

Comment: Oops! Yes That was Doug Coats. Thank you for your edits - :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
IC.[Retention Limit]-SUM([Net Invoice Amt]) AS Remaining, MD.[Claim Number], IC.[Retention Limit], IC.InsuranceID
FROM tbl_InsuranceCoverage IC
INNER JOIN tbl_MatterDetail MD ON ic.InsuranceID = MD.Policy
INNER JOIN tbl_PaymentProcessing PP ON MD.MatterDetailID=pp.MatterDetailID AND MD.[Claim Number]=pp.[Claim Number]
GROUP BY MD.[Claim Number], IC.[Retention Limit], IC.InsuranceID
```

See if this works. Havent tested it but seems simple. You can remove the extra columns, but this will hlep you understand joins a bit

Comment: Awesome - I just had to play around the relationship in SQL a bit but this code worked perfectly.

Comment: glad I could help